# How frequent is "for" used to mean "because"?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

In [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/166541/the-of-in-the-a-high-level-of-civilization) is the sentence

> The city must have been prosperous, for it enjoyed a high level of civilization.

Although I understand the meaning, I must admit I never realized "for" could be used as "because", which I discovered in an [online dictionnary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for). I also don't remember any lesson about it in school (but I basically only had a few hours a week in secondary school and then learned by myself, so this might explain that). Therefore I was wondering if it can replace "because" in any occasion and any level of speach or if there were "rules" indicating you should use one rather than the other (or even forbidding to use it)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any way to establish how frequently **for** is used in the sense of **because** or **because of**.

Being shorter, **for** is likely to be used more often, especially in conversation.

Note, however, that the two words are not always interchangeable and the choice will often depend on the context.

While you can say either:

> We are staying at home because rain is expected this afternoon
>   or
>   We are staying at home for rain is expected this afternoon

You can't use **for** at the start of a sentence to mean **because**:

> Because he broke his leg, he is confined to his house.
>   NOT: >For he broke his leg, he is confined to his house.

Although you can use it if you reverse the sentence:

> He is confined to his house for he broke his leg.

Comment: Can you elaborate an example where you can't use both depending on the context and not only because of the position in the sentence?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56394/for-vs-because            https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/using-for-to-mean-because

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I didn't find this answer before...

Comment: "For want of a naile a shoe was lost..."

Comment: "For lack of a better word..."