# What does "for" mean in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, syntax

> Clearly Glass is no longer accurate when he says "there is no structure at all -the structure defines itself from moment to moment", **for** it is precisely the expectation that something different will happen next time around that motivates our perception of the music.

What does the function of *for* here? I looked up OALD to find sentences with "say for" and there was none except this one:

> I'll say this for them, they're a very efficient company.

Nonetheless, I believe *for* in the block-quoted sentence has a different function than it has in the aforementioned sentence.

Does *for* in the block-quote mean Glass said the sentence in the quotation marks ("there is no structure at all...") agrees with the sentence following *for* ("it is precisely..."), or to disagree with it and/or exaggerate it? What does the sentence structure suggest and what is the function of *for* here?

[Source](http://www.paristransatlantic.com/magazine/archives/minimalism.html)

Comment: Forget *says for*. Substitute *since* in the place of *for*, for that is its purpose there: Glass is pretending he has no structure **since** we expect music to surprise us (within its structure). Structure and surprise do not contradict, they tease each other. The part after *for* contradicts Glass's claim.

Comment: *[I'll say this] **for** [him]* = ***in support of***. As opposed to, say, ***about*** - which could be followed by a negative ***or*** positive statement. Probably not a "neutral" statement though, since one would have little reason to explicitly *announce* that you're gonna make a neutral statement in such contexts.

Comment: The author is arguing with the Glass statement. Glass says his piece has no structure at all, it jumps around carefree. That's untrue **for the reason that** repetition and variation in music are normal.

Comment: There is some trouble reaching the quote in the originally quoted source, so I updated the question with another, where the entire article is available.

Comment: No; it has the same function in both cases, i.e. head of a preposition phrase. "For" is one of the most polysemous of all the main prepositions of English with a plethora of subtly different meanings, as well as a handful of grammaticised uses. In your first example, it expresses reason, rather like the preposition "because" does. In the second it means, roughly, "in support of". Meanings aside, syntactically, in both your examples, "for" is a preposition functioning as **head** of a preposition phrase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How frequent is "for" used to mean "because"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/237502/how-frequent-is-for-used-to-mean-because)

Answer (score 4):

"[For](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/for)" means many things and has many uses, but in this case, "[for](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/for)" (see definition 34) is used as a [coordinating conjunction](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/coordinating-conjunctions/) that means "[because](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/because)."

> **[for](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/for)**
>
> *conjunction*
> 34. because.

Comment: I'd say it 's a preposition functioning as head of the PPs "for it is precisely the expectation that ..." and "I'll say this for them,...". The conjunction (subordinator) "for" only occurs in _to-_ infinitival clauses that have a subject, e.g. "For Ed to lose his temper like that is highly unusual".

Answer (score 1):

In this syntactic context  "for"  is considered  usually to be a conjunction of  *subordination* (meaning "because", not used much except  in literary text), although some will call it rather a conjunction of coordination.

There is a serious argument for classifying "for" as a subordinating conjunction  (CoGEL § 13.18).

> **13.18** **Coordination-subordination gradient**
> Table 13.18 displays the gradient from the central coordinators *and* and *or* to subordinators like *if* and *because*, with *but, for*, and *so that* on the gradient. The conjuncts *yet, so*, and *nor* are added to the Table, because, as we have seen, they in some respects resemble coordinators. The six features of *and* and *or* noted in 13.7-17 have provided six criteria used in constructing the matrix. If an item satisfies a criterion, this is indicated by a '+' in the relevant cell. If it fails to satisfy the criterion, '-' is entered. The combination '±' takes care of cases, explained in the previous discussion, where the item satisfies the criterion only under certain conditions. The six criteria to be  applied to each item are :
> (a) It is immobile in front of its clause.
> (b) A clause beginning with it is sequentially fixed in relation to the previous clause, and hence cannot be moved to a position in front of that clause.
> (c) It does not allow a conjunction to precede it.
> (d) It links not only clauses, but predicates and other clause constituents.
> (e) It can link subordinate clauses.
> (f) It can link more than two clauses, and when it does so all but the final
> instance of the linking item can be omitted.
>
> Table 13.18 Coordination-conjunct-subordination gradients
>
> | (a) | (b) | (c) | (d) | (e) | (f) |  |  |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | + | + | + | + | + | + | **coordinators** | *and, or* |
> | + | + | + | + | ± | - |  | *but* |
> | + | + | x | + | - | - | **conjuncts** | *yet, so, nor* |
> | - | + | - | - | - | - |  | *however, therefore* |
> | + | + | + | - | - | - | **subordinators** | *for, so that* |
> | + | ± | - | - | - | - |  | *if, because* |

It can  be seen  that  the criteria  that make  "and" and "or"  true   coordinators fail  in the case of  "for". "For"  is  therefore  more  akin  to because", which  is  definitely at the subordinator end of the  gradient.

> (**CoGEL§2.60**)
> [...] there is a scale relating coordinating and subordinating conjunctions, such that *and* and *if*  represent clear cases of each category, whereas *for* is in an intermediate position:
> COORDINATING                   SUBORDINATING
>     and<--------------for------------>if
> Nevertheless, *for* is closer to *if* in its syntactic behaviour than to "and" , and can reasonably be classed as a peripheral subordinator.

**Note**     "For" is   not a  preposition  because  the  prepositional complement is  "characteristically a noun  phrase, a nominal *wh*-clause or a nomial *-ing* clause" (*CoGEL* § 9.1). There  is  not  a  complement   in  what follows  "for"; instead there is a finite verb form ("is"), which is  the mark of  a finite  clause; this  syntax can only justify "for"  as  a subordinator (or a  coordinator, according  to  those who ould rather treat it  as such).

Comment: -1 for a poor answer. The "for" in the OP's example is a preposition functioning as head of the PPs "for it is precisely ...", and "for them". Note that preps like "for" take not only NP complements but also clauses. "For" is only a subordinator when it occurs in _to_- infinitival clauses that have a subject, e.g. "For Ed to lose his temper like that is highly unusual". Elsewhere it's a preposition.

Comment: CGEL states that "for" is a preposition that can take finite clause complements. It gives this example: _He avoided answering [for he was afraid of implicating his wife]_.

Comment: @BillJ  CGEL is aberrant on this point. See this: "[Prepositional phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adpositional_phrase#Prepositional_phrases) have a preposition as the central element of the phrase, i.e. as the head of the phrase. The remaining part of the phrase is called the prepositional complement, or sometimes the "object" of the preposition. In English and many other Indo-European languages it takes the form of a noun phrase, such as a noun, pronoun, or gerund, possibly with one or more modifiers."...   [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prepositional%20phrase)

Comment: Not in English, which permits a wide range of complements to prepositions. "For" is clearly a preposition, much like "because", both of which take finite clause complements.

Comment: @BillJ With all the good will I might muster to try and accept your point of view, I don't believe I'll ever be able to see any logic in it; I see absolutely no logic in it.